# chirality in geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

It was trying to undertsand the quantity that would define chirality for sufficiently smooth surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$. A motivation for this is the "notion" of handedness defined for a ruled surface
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}(s,v) = \mathbf{d}(s)+v\mathbf{g}(s),
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{d}$ is the directrix and $\mathbf{g}$ is the generatrix or the ruling of the ruled surface.The handedness is usually defined by the sign of the determinant :
\begin{equation}
det[\mathbf{\dot{d}}, \mathbf{g}, \mathbf{\dot{g}}].
\end{equation}

But even here the determinant vanishes for a developable surface, although I intuitively feel that the notion of left handed or right handed would still be valid for developable surfaces which are not planar. I am not sure how one would quantify this.

In general, if I have a surface of revolution or other surfaces, how would chirality be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In geometry in general, a subset of a Euclidean space is said to be chiral or have chirality if it is not congruent to its mirror image.

That is, if there does not exist a rotation and translation of the mirror object that would make it exactly align with the original.

For surfaces of revolution, this amounts to the object being symmetric front to back down the axis of revolution. Specifically, if we generate a surface S by revolving the graph of $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ around the x axis, then S is chiral if and only if $f(b-(x-a))\neq f(x)$ for some $x\in[a,b]$

Comment: thanks a lot. I do have a small follow up, if you dont mind. Does the definition of chirality I have given for ruled surfaces agree with what you say. I am a bit confused. Can you explain how you arrived at the condition for surfaces for revolution?

Comment: Also, then flat surfaces would be achiral? But still if I have a paper Mobius strip with a left handed twist, shouldnt it be different from the one with right handed one?

Comment: The determinant expression that you gave will measure the orientation of the parameterization locally. Orientation is a different concept from chirality. It is true that a flat surface (Im assuming you mean a 2D object) is not chiral when you allow yourself to rotate it in 3 dimensions. And a mobius band is indeed chiral!

Comment: Aah..okay...thanks...but in the case of ruled surfaces, are the chirality and orientation issues connected?For example, in circular helicoids, would I get chiral counterpart of a right twisted one by changing the sign of the determinant.

Comment: not that I know of, but I don't know much about rules surfaces at all ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I will leave the question open for some time more to see if I can get an answer which particularly addresses the extra doubts I have, else will accept yours.